# React-Native fetch call to localhost endpoint is giving Type Error: Network request failed when using https

Tags: .net-core, react-native

I have a react-native application running on expo client using `npm run android` on **Android Studio Emulator**, WebApi call to get data using fetch works perfectly fine when I disable Enable SSL on the Visual Studio project settings see below, which means it is running on http port **54715**, if you see arrow mark I unchecked Enable SSL checkbox

[image]

And also I made changes in applicationhost.config file to point my localhost to 127.0.0.1 which is an alias for 10.0.2.2 to connect from Android emulator, see below:

```
 <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54715:127.0.0.1" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54715:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44367:127.0.0.1" />
 </bindings>
```

So from above if I make fetch call from react native app it is working just fine, see code below:

```
fetch("http://10.0.2.2:54715/WeatherForecast/getAllProgramTypes")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

But the moment I click on EnableSSL on the project properties it would run on https port which is self certified

https://10.0.2.2:44367/WeatherForecast/getAllProgramTypes

https run on **44367** port, and when I make fetch to the web api:

```
fetch("https://10.0.2.2:44367/WeatherForecast/getAllProgramTypes")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

now with https I am getting **TypeError: Network request failed**, it is unable to make https call on localhost.

I got it working with http when I un-check Enable SSL and run the .Net Core solution but how to make fetch call with local https work ?

When I look at Microsoft docs it says **Bypass the certificate security check**, how do i do it with react-native code ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#bypass-the-certificate-security-check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, http or https even if it's working on Android Emulator, the question again is how it will work on your iPhone device or an Android device, I mean if you are using Expo Client app to open you react native app, now how do you connect your localhost .NET Core WebApi or any other endpoints on your local machine to your mobile devices to have the app running.

I have a common working solution which works for both emulators and mobile apps on the individual devices.

Step 1: Go to https://ngrok.com/

Step 2: Sign Up, you may use GitHub account

Step 3: Click on Download for windows if you have windows OS and unzip the file, you will
see the .exe, copy that to your desktop or the location you wanted.

Step 4: Go windows explorer and open command prompt on the location where you copied the
exe, run `dir` to check to see if you have ngrok.exe in the location you are on.

Step 5: Run `ngrok authtoken yourTokenGivenDuringSignUp` , it’s one-time thing you may need
to do

Step 6: Run  `ngrok http https://localhost:PortNumber -host-header="localhost:PortNumber"` , Port number is the port that your .NET core solution is running, Enable SSL in the project properties we need https for this to work.

Step 7: Copy https link which will be ngrok created https URL which is highlighted, given as below example

[image]

Now you can use above link to replace in the fetch url to make the mobile app or Emulators work from your local code.

Note*** We need to be running the ngrok on step 6 & our solution, also url is different every time so run the step 6 and .NET Core solution to generate new web address and use it in the react native app.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Ciao unfortunately seems that is not possible to bypass the certificate security check in Javascript.
Possible solution:

1. Add the self-signed certificate to your root certificate repository on your local machine.
2. Obtain a valid signed certificate from a free service such as [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).